# returning a result with node async waterfall in loopbackJS

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, loopbackjs, node-async

I understand that with the recent version of async waterfall, cb is no longer available.

That being the case, how do give a remote method a response?  I can't seem to find this explained anywhere.

To use an example from the async documentation.

```
async.waterfall([
    function(callback) {
        callback(null, 'one', 'two');
    },
    function(arg1, arg2, callback) {
        // arg1 now equals 'one' and arg2 now equals 'two'
        callback(null, 'three');
    },
    function(arg1, callback) {
        // arg1 now equals 'three'
        callback(null, 'done');
    }
], function (err, result) {
    // result now equals 'done'

    // HOW DO I RETURN result TO THE CALLER OF THE REMOTE METHOD?
    // HOW DO I RETURN result TO THE CALLER OF THE REMOTE METHOD?
    // HOW DO I RETURN result TO THE CALLER OF THE REMOTE METHOD?


});
```

EDIT: Here is the actual event that I am trying to pass a response back from.  In previous versions of async ,this was just done by passing it into cb().. but it appears this is no longer supported by async.

```
Ticket.addComment = function( id, comment, postedBy, cb ) {

    async.waterfall([

      //get ticket and add content
      function(callback){
        Ticket.findById( id, function( err, ticket ){
          ticket.ticketComments.create({ "body": comment });
          callback(null, ticket);
        });
      },

      //update ticket isWith
      function(ticket, callback){
        ticket.save(null, {
          "id": ticket.id,
          "isWith": postedBy
        });
        callback(null,ticket);
      }

    ], function( err, ticket ){

       // I NEED TO RETURN "ticket" TO THE METHOD CALLER.. THIS USED TO BE DONE BY PASSING "ticket" INTO cb().

    });

  }

  Ticket.remoteMethod('addComment', {
    http: { verb: 'post'},
    accepts: [
      {arg: 'id', type: 'string', description: 'ticket id of the ticket the comment is to be added to'},
      {arg: 'comment', type: 'string', description: 'the comment body'},
      {arg: 'postedBy', type: 'string', description: 'Who posted the comment'}
    ],
    returns: {arg: 'comment', root: true, type: 'application/json'}
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var create = function (req, res) {
        async.waterfall([
            _function1(req),
            _function2,
            _function3
        ], function (error, success) {
            if (error) { alert('Something is wrong!'); }
            return alert('Done!');
        });
    };
    function _function1 (req) {
        return function (callback) {
            var something = req.body;
            callback (null, something);
       }
    }

    function _function2 (something, callback) {
        return function (callback) {
           var somethingelse = function () { // do something here };
           callback (err, somethingelse);
        }
    }

    function _function3 (something, callback) {
        return function (callback) {
          var somethingmore = function () { // do something here };
          callback (err, somethingmore);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: **You don't**. That is not the way to program asynchronously.

Is it possible to devise ways of making the caller wait for the async call to end and get its result. But doing that defeats the purpose of programming asynchronously.

So, if you have code that needs the results of the `async.waterfall` it *MUST* be placed on the final callback.

Here an example of how this is usually accomplished:

```
Ticket.addComment = function( id, comment, postedBy, cb ) {

  async.waterfall([

    //get ticket and add content
    function(callback){
      Ticket.findById( id, function( err, ticket ){
        ticket.ticketComments.create({ "body": comment });
        callback(null, ticket);
      });
    },

    //update ticket isWith
    function(ticket, callback){
      ticket.save(null, {
        "id": ticket.id,
        "isWith": postedBy
      });
      callback(null,ticket);
    }
  ], function( err, ticket){
    // Instead of returning to the caller, use your result here
    Ticket.remoteMethod('addComment', {
      http: { verb: 'post'},
      accepts: [
        {arg: 'ticket', type: 'whatever', value: ticket, description: 'an example of how you could return the result'},
        {arg: 'id', type: 'string', description: 'ticket id of the ticket the comment is to be added to'},
        {arg: 'comment', type: 'string', description: 'the comment body'},
        {arg: 'postedBy', type: 'string', description: 'Who posted the comment'}
      ],
      returns: {arg: 'comment', root: true, type: 'application/json'}
    });
    cb(); // <-- not forgetting the callback
  });

}
```

**Note**: On your code the methods `Ticket.findById`, `ticket.save` and `Ticket.remoteMethod` look synchronous. They basically defeat the purpose of having your code using `async.waterfall`: each function within `waterfall()` will block. Unless you find an async version of those methods you should remove the async altogether. It is just making your code more complicated without any significant benefit.

Comment: Hi flaviodesousa.. yes, I need to return something.  It is an API call that updates a ticket.. and I need the ticket returned.  Can you explain what you mean by it must be placed on the final callback? I am doing that, but doesn't seem to be passing back to the API call.  I will update the ticket with the actual event that I am trying to pass a response from. Thanks

Comment: Added an example on how usually async code looks like. There are some issues with your API though, it does not look async.